# Como utilizar anotação @Delete no Vraptor + AJAX?

Tags: ajax, vraptor

No meu projeto Vraptor estou tentando deletar um registro de uma lista sem que a pagina seja recarregada. Pelo livro que estou seguindo, utiliza-se AJAX para que o registro removido "suma" sem que toda a pagina seja carregada.
O erro abaixo ocorre quando tento usar a anotação @Delete do vraptor.

**HTTP Status 405 -**

type: **Status report**

description: **The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.**

**Meu controller:**

```
@Controller
@Path("/pessoa")
public class PessoaController {
[...]

@Delete("/remove/{codPessoa}")
public void remove(Long codPessoa) {
Pessoa pessoaEncontrada = repository.findById(codPessoa, 1);
    if (pessoaEncontrada != null) {
       repository.delete(pessoaEncontrada);
       result.nothing();
    } else
       result.notFound();
}}
```

**Na pagina JSP:**

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#pessoas.remove").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var pessoa = $(this).closest(".pessoa");
    });
    $.ajax({
        url : $(this).attr("href"),
        type : "POST",
        data : {_method : "DELETE"}
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        pessoa.fadeOut();
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Cliente não foi alterado! " + errorThrown);
    });
```

[...]

```
<ul id=pessoas>
    <c:forEach items="${pessoaList}" var="pessoa">
        <li class="pessoa">${pessoa.codPessoa}-${pessoa.nomeFantasia}
            <a href="${linkTo[PessoaController].edita(pessoa.codPessoa, pessoa.codEmpresa)}"> -Editar</a> 
            <a class="remove" href="${linkTo[PessoaController].remove(pessoa.codPessoa)}"> -Remover</a>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está tentando fazer um `POST` para um recurso que só aceita `DELETE`, A solução é fácil, você só precisa indicar corretamente qual método html você quer usar na requisição:

```
$.ajax({
    url : $(this).attr("href"),
    method : "DELETE"
})
```

Caso você esteja usando uma versão do jQuery anterior a 1.9.0, ao invés de `method` use `type` mesmo. Qualquer dúvida sobre os atributos do método ajax, dê uma conferida na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Juliano... Os atributos "type:'POST'" e "data: _method : "DELETE" é um recurso para que a ação funcione em qualquer browser, segundo o livro que estou usando para estudo. Mesmo mudando para forma que propôs não resolveu meu problema. Acredito que seja alguma particularidade do VRaptor. Valeu @juliano

Comment: @raphaRezzi isso é válido para que o <form> se comporte dessa forma, mas não é assim para js. Você pode verificar isso aqui https://jsfiddle.net/qv8fw9g9/ abrindo o console do seu chrome e clicando em cada botão, você vai ver que da forma que você sugere, é feito um post, e como sugeri é um delete. Ainda sim, já que não resolveu, compartilhe o erro para ficar mais fácil ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer funcionar. Mas não usando o @Delete. Na verdade, atributo "_method: 'DELETE'" é um parâmetro que passado para o VRaptor (segundo o que li).
Solução: Substitui o @Delete por @Path no método e a exclusão foi realizada. O erro que estava cometendo é que no meu script (js), o **$.ajax** estava fora da *function*, e o seletor **#pessoas.remove** deveria ter um espaço entre "#pessoas" e ".remove" (**"#pessoas .remove"**). Mudando essas estruturas a implementação deu certo.

Comment: Depois das alterações na _function_ js, pode usar a anotação **Delete** no lugar do **Path** no método do controller.